# Move a mail from a folder to another folder in R

Tags: r, outlook

I've been trying to move one (or several) mails from "inbox" folder to "TEST" folder nested in "Other" folder.
But I can't find a way to do so.

I'm able to manipulate and get attributes of the mail but impossible to move an email.
My next solution would be to fwd that email, named with a specific name, and then create in outlook a rule depending on the subject. And delete the original one.
But that's not the best way to me.

Do you have any clue ?
I tried to assign the following way but it doesn't work...

```
  folderName = "Inbox"

  ## create outlook object
  OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
  outlookNameSpace = OutApp$GetNameSpace("MAPI")

  ### number 226 is the index of one of the mail I'd like to move
  outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)$Folders("Other")$Folders("TEST")[["Items"]] <- outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)$Folders(folderName)$Items(226)
  outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)$Folders("Other")$Folders("TEST")["Items"][1] <- outlookNameSpace$Folders(1)$Folders(folderName)$Items(226)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [MailItem.Move](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.move) which moves a Microsoft Outlook item to a new folder.

Comment: Great ! it was the documentation I was looking for !